# Perl Module to convert OWL files to OBO

Tags: perl-module

I am new to Perl and have never used a CPAN module before, I need to convert an OWL file to OBO format. I successfully installed the  "ONTO-PERL-1.37" module. I want to use the following script:

```
use Carp;
use strict;
use warnings;

use OBO::Parser::OWLParser;

my $my_parser = OBO::Parser::OWLParser->new();
my $ontology = $my_parser->work(shift(@ARGV));
$ontology->export('obo');

exit 0;
```

**END**

My question is do i need to declare the input OWL file, if yes how can that be done for the above script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script takes the argument from the command line. This is what the `shift(@ARGV)` is for. `shift` removes the first element from a list and `@ARGV` is a list filled with the filename given as a command line argument, when running the script with `perl owl2obo.pl my-ontology.owl`.

If it easier, you can modify the script with

```
 my $ontology = $my_parser->work('/the/path/to/ontology.owl');
```

or

```
 my $owlfile = shift(@ARGV) || '/path/to/owlfile.owl';
 my $ontology = $my_parser->work($owlfile);
```

.